# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, error-handling, out-of-memory

```
04-11 15:00:57.646 30603-30603/com.Blufish.blufish E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.Blufish.blufish, PID: 30603
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Blufish.blufish/com.Blufish.blufish.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2487)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.Blufish.blufish.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:53)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:649)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.Blufish.blufish.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:53) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.Blufish.blufish.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:53) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 864216012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 162MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:613)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:446)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
        at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2952)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2684)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2580)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:398)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:872)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3963)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:570)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:566)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:575)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.Blufish.blufish.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:53) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

LoginActivity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_img"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/user" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_username"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/login_username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lpassword"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_pass"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/login_pass"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/login"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signbutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/sign_up"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginbutton" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.40218878" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progressBar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signbutton"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/blufish" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This Error does not comes when i use phones with Android Oreo or higher Version.
But, when I am trying this app in Android Marshmallow with 3GB RAM this error pops up.

Things I have tried while looking up in google are:

1) Added com.android.support:design:28.0.0

2) Added android:largeHeap="true"

3) Copied all of my drawable items in drawable-v24 folder

Above methods did not give any positive results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your drawable resource is such big that there is not enough memory for it to be loaded.

First, if it is not meant to be that high-resolution, I would recommend you to provide different images for each screen pixel densities. Check out [this(Support different pixel densities)](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) for more information.

Second, if you want to load that high-resolution image anyway, you should consider not loading it completely to the memory. Check out [this(Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently)](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) for more information about loading a large image efficiently.

Comment: Can you help me in little more detail as to how to implement this in my application thanks a lot.

Comment: @Abhinav follow the instructions provided in the linked documents. I think they should be sufficient. And also as mentioned in the doc you can use libraries such as Glide, Picasso, Coil, Fresco, ... to have them do this for you. But in short if I want to explain the problem, it happens because when images are loaded into the memory they take much more space (4 byte for each pixel) than the file size.

Comment: Ok i will try with this links and if I unable to do it I will consult you, I am marking your answer till then thanks.