# android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android

I have a very frustrating error that I cannot explain. I created an Android application that uses Androidx AppCompat to make it compatible with older versions. Here is my main activity layout file:
{Androidx}.

**here is my java file:**

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, 1500);
}
```

**here is my xml file:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash_screen"
tools:context=".Activities.SplashScreen">
```

**here is my gradle file**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bloodbank"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}
**dependencies in gradle file**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

}

The main problem is my app says that **unfortunately app has stopped**.
**here is the details in the run tab**

> D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap D/AndroidRuntime:
>   Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.bloodbank, PID: 3542
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bloodbank/com.example.bloodbank.Activities.SplashScreen}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
>           at com.example.bloodbank.Activities.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:16)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
>           at com.example.bloodbank.Activities.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:16) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 711998476 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 383MB until OOM
>           at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
>           at android.view.View.(View.java:3737)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:497)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:493)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:489)
>           at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.(ConstraintLayout.java:575)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
>           at com.example.bloodbank.Activities.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:16) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)  Process
>   3542 terminated.

it shows error in 16th line of `splashcreen.java`
please help me in clearing this error .

Thanks

Comment: please add gradle file where you are defining constraint layout dependency

Comment: Your code looks ok though please check if end tag of your androidx.constraintlayout is correct. it should end with />

Comment: end tag is closed correctly . there is no syntax kind of errors. build finished correctly but while running app it crashes.(i missed my end tag for that code while posting question. sorry for that )

Comment: i added my gradle file . please make a look at it!

Comment: You might some special character that can't be seen in an editor. Error is straight forward: `InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually getting a `OutOfMemoryException`. It happens when you put a high-resolution image directly in your view. In your case, probably `@drawable/splash_screen`.

Check out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154757/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-2-binary-xml-file-line-2). An answer is provided for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the XML you've pasted is complete or not. If it is, that's an error right there. The Constraint Layout needs a closing tag.

Comment: end tag is closed properly. i misssed it to paste it here.